# Google AdSense - language

Tags: adsense

I want to add Google AdSense on my site and I want adds to be in X language (not English). How can I tell google which language is used on the site?

Thanks!

Comment: google supports only some limited languages. If your site contains any one of those languages then only they allow you to put google adds. other i think it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9727

> You can select your site's primary
>   language during the application
>   process. If you're approved, AdSense
>   will serve relevant ads to your pages
>   in the appropriate language, even if
>   your site contains multiple supported
>   languages.

Comment: But I have diferent sites... some are in EN some in different languages... ??

Comment: How can I become approved? :)